# Custom Fill Exclusions Variable for Choropleth

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm currently putting together a choropleth based on Nielsens US DMAs. I'm nearly there, however I'm wondering if it's possible to set a aes fill variable to have exceptions. See below for current code:

```
gg <- ggplot()
> gg <- gg + geom_map(data=neil_map, map=neil_map,aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),color="white", size=0.05, fill=NA)
> gg <- gg + geom_map(data=data_merged, map=neil_map,aes(fill=CTR, map_id=MID),color="white", size=0.05)
> gg <- gg + coord_proj(paste0("+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96"," +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"))
> gg <- gg + theme_map()
> gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="bottom")
> gg <- gg + theme(legend.key.width=unit(2, "cm"))
> gg
```

See below for output[image]:

What I'm trying to achieve is have a color scale on all values >0, but if value = 0, I want the DMA to be a different color. Is this a possibility, and if so, how would I go about achieving this. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for a way to combine continuous and discrete color scales (continuous for the positive and discrete for the zeros)

In [this qustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224007/combine-continuous-and-discrete-color-scale-in-ggplot2) there is a solution for dealling with infinite values or NA's.
You can do the same thing here. 
(I wanted to write this in a comment, but my reputation in the site isn't high enogh) 
Hope this helps